# MySQL, allow only certain types of users to be able to alter a field

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a database for a simple system. The two relevant tables for this question are Users and Categories. They are set as follows:

Users : UserId(Pk), Username, User Type, First Name etc..

Categories: CategoryId(Pk), Name, UserId(Fk)

I have set User Type to be an 'enum' and can only have the values admin,moderator or regular. I want to be make it so that only a user with type admin can add a category table.

Is there a way that this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users is not also MySQL users, which I assume they are not, then this is not up to MySQL but rather the program interfacing with MySQL, i.e: PHP. You should do the appropriate checks before committing changes to the "restricted" tables.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have to deal with privileges. 
Look at the pages https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html
and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html.

We have the GRANT statement to provide a privileges to the users

here is the simple example :
If you want to specify the only select privileges to user kim from localhost to the table 
users ,

GRANT select on dbname.users to 'kim'@'localhost' identified by 'password'

to specify all privileges to any user

GRANT all on dbname.users to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'pass'

To check the permissions of any particular user

use :  `show grants [for user ]`

The thing which is under brackets is optional , user in the sense a valid user like 'root'@'%'